# Pseudo elemento en el header no se desplaza a la tab activa

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo un header con una `<nav>` que contiene el siguiente código:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#MyNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
            <li class="nav-item juose">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">STAT <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="inv.html">INV</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">DATA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">MAP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">RADIO</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

La cuestión es que he creado un pseudo elemento que consiste en una  serie de líneas que recubre la tab  activa de la nav anterior según cual sea la activa en el momento, sin embargo mi problema es que siempre se queda en la misma ventana y no se desplaza hacia la que está activa, esta es una foto del pseudo elemento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código css del elemento:

```
li.nav-item.juose::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #252921;
    width: 14%;
    height: 22px;
    left: 216px;
    top: 33px;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-top: 2px solid;
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que cuando hago que otra ventana esté activa, por ejemplo INV, tal que así:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#MyNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/pipboy/index.html">STAT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item juose">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="/pipboy/inv.html">INV <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

El psuedo elemento se queda en STAT y sé que tiene que ver con el CSS del elemento, pero he probado todo y no soy capaz de hacer que se desplace hacia la nueva ventana activa INV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta sería una solución, lo que pasa es que estas haciendo el `postition:absolute;` sobre toda la pagina y lo tendrías que hacer de dentro del `.jouose`

```
    li.nav-item.juose {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    li.nav-item.juose::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background: #252921;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 22px;
        border-left: 2px solid;
        border-right: 2px solid;
        border-top: 2px solid;
    }
```

Comment: efectivamente, he adaptado la caja al nuevo estilo y ahora si funciona, entonces todos los pseudo-elementos deben de ser absolut y su elemento en el que están contenidos relative?

Comment: exacto siempre que quieras que dependa de un div hijo

Comment: pensaba que por default, a no ser que lo modificase era relative